# MongoDB - Update with python

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7

I want to try add more values to array, but therefor two values must match. I get it working with one value, but not with two. This is what I have:

```
    { "_id" : ObjectId( "50f1a05d00bf6832b03a01cb" ),
  "app" : "494258956",
  "keywords" : [ 
    { "data" : [ 
        { "device" : "software",
          "date" : Date( 1358012509633 ),
          "rank" : 1,
          "shop" : "143443" } ],
      "keyword" : "test" } ] }
```

When I have a new "data" for the keyword "test" and app "494258956", then a new set should be added to "data" and look like this:

```
    { "_id" : ObjectId( "50f1a05d00bf6832b03a01cb" ),
  "app" : "494258956",
  "keywords" : [ 
    { "data" : [ 
        { "device" : "software",
          "date" : Date( 1358012509633 ),
          "rank" : 1,
          "shop" : "143443" }
 , { "device" : "software",
          "date" : Date( 1358012599633 ),
          "rank" : 2,
          "shop" : "143443" }],
      "keyword" : "test" } ] }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check out $push operator http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/push/

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do what you're asking (JavaScript syntax):

```
    coll.update({
        "app": "494258956", 
        "keywords": {
            "$elemMatch": { "keyword": "test" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$push": {
            "keywords.$.data": {
                "device" : "software",
                "date" : new Date( 1358012599633 ),
                "rank" : 2,
                "shop" : "143443" 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. It works if the keyword exists, but not if it doesn't exist and the dataset must be inserted. I just get a $. Do you know a solution how it can work?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is too complicated for an "upsert" operation.  I think you'll need to test for result of the update, and do an insert when the item couldn't be found.

Answer (score 0):

Currently this isn't supported - because the positional operator `$` doesn't currently work with upsert.  Please vote for [SERVER-3326](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3326)

Workarounds might be to revisit the schema design or multiple operations where you don't use a upsert - and inspect the number of items updated.  You have to take care not to hit a race condition eg:

1. Do an update where `{keywords: {$exists: true}}`
2. If update returns 0 - no keywords perform an upsert: where `{keywords: {$exists: false}}`
3. If update returns 0 - there was a race and someone added keywords can now perform step 1.